# NiFi EvaluateJsonPath array length

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jsonpath, json-path-expression

I have the following JSON:

```
{
    "hits": {
         "hits":[]
    }
}
```

(Some response from ElasticSearch).

I want to use the processor `EvaluateJsonPath` to get the length of `hits.hits`.

I tried the following expression:

`$.hits.hits.length`

But I get the following error:

`FlowFile could not find path $['hits']['hits']['length'] for attribute key hits.:` (That's the end of the error).

However, when checking online with JsonEvaluate sites it seems to work.

What's wrong with my expression?

Comment: `.length()` https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#jayway-jsonpath

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that there are different versions of `JsonPath`. For me, `$.hits.hits.length()` worked.